# Reading tiffs in opencv swaps top and bottom third of image

Tags: python, image, opencv, tiff, fits

I've got a pretty strange issue.  I have several tif images of astronomical objects.  I'm trying to use opencv's python bindings to process them.  Upon reading the image file, it appears that segments of the images are swapped or rotated.  I've stripped it down to the bare minimum, and it still reproduces:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.tif', 0)
cv2.imwrite('image_unaltered.tif', img)
```

I've uploaded some samples to imgur, to show the effect.  The images aren't super clear, that's the nature of preprocessed astronomical images, but you can see it:

First set:

[image: image 1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XtDo.jpg

[image: image 2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIHRo.jpg

Second set:

[image: image 3]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQVgB.jpg

[image: image 4]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/43XrU.jpg

The same rotated/swapped images appear if I use `cv2.imShow(...)` as well, so I believe it's something when I read the file.  Furthermore, it persists if I save as jpg as well.  Opening the original in Photoshop shows the correct image.  I'm using opencv 2.4.10, on Linux Mint 17.1.  If it matters, the original tifs were created with FITS liberator on windows.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Bizarre--if I recall correctly (I'll double check though) OpenCV is actually using PyFITS to load FITS images, and might be doing something odd there.  Do you have any experience using PyFITS and matplotlib to display images?  If so, does that display the images correctly?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your original issue--I see now that the files are converted to tiff.  I guess OpenCV doesn't support FITS directly--I was confusing with a different project.

Comment: Any way you can post the original TIFF image? IMGUR turns everything into a PNG. I'm guessing that the original image is recorded in 3 strips and OpenCV is messing up the reading of it.

Comment: "Original" tiff uploaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6644826/hst_05237_02_wfpc2_f656n_wf_sci.tif).  I say original in quotes because it was originally originally a FITS...